# How to determine if a DLL requires Full .NET 4 or just Client Profile

Tags: .net, dll, .net-4.0, .net-client-profile

When using third party assemblies I need a way to detect if they require full .NET 4 or just the .NET 4 Client Profile.

I've seen other ways to detect .NET version referenced [Determine .NET Framework version for dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3460982/determine-net-framework-version-for-dll) but the ways outlined in that question do not show how to detect Client Profile vs Full. Is it possible?

I'm looking for any solution, it doesn't have to be a code/runtime solution.

Comment: You could manually check references for those which are not included with the Client Profile (or write a tool to do this for you!). I'm not sure of a way out of the box.

Comment: AFAIK, When using only the assemblies only Client Profile is needed, Full .net framework is required for development/debugging purposes.

Comment: Any solution will work, doesn't have to be code only.

Comment: @Furqan, that is not true, Client Profile is a slimmed down version that is sufficient to run most console/desktop applications. Full is typically needed for server applications even in production. For example, `System.Web` does not exist in Client Profile but does in Full. That is needed for anything related to any aspx/mvc/wcf/etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>**Please note** that the solution below is specific to the .NET 4.0 framework, the `TargetFrameworkAttribue` is new to 4.0.</sub>

I compiled two applications, one against the Client Framework, the other against the full. I opened them both in ildasm.exe and noticed they both had a [`TargetFrameworkAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.versioning.targetframeworkattribute.aspx) applied. You can simply use reflection to see the value:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Versioning;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        var att = a.GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<TargetFrameworkAttribute>().Single();

        Console.WriteLine(att.FrameworkDisplayName);
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

**Update:** Yes indeed, compiling an application against the ".NET Framework 3.5 Client Profile" does ***not*** include that attribute (the code can no longer see it and ildasm doesn't feature it). I have no clue, other than the other answer you linked, as to how to determine the target framework in this situation.

To save imposing what ***I*** see as pointless limitations on your code base, I would make life easier and simply target the full framework. If the client has permissions on installing the Client Profile, then the same is true for the Full framework - it is just slightly larger (I spotted a source saying it was only 15% larger, thereby negating much of the "smaller client package" benefit, 41MB as opposed to 48MB). Your call.