# How to determine what version of Framework a DLL targets?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, dll, frameworks

If a Visual Studio 2010 project references an external DLL:

- How can you find out what version of the Framework the DLL targets?
- Does the project need to target that version of the Framework as well?

Comment: The project's framework must be the ddl framework, minimum. Else you can not add them.

Comment: You have nothing to do, If it is higher version than current project VS will complain you

Comment: Its already answered elsewhere. Please check - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3460982/determine-net-framework-version-for-dll

Comment: An assembly doesn't target a .NET Framework version, it targets a CLR version.  That got murky in .NET 4.5, you can see the [TargetFramework] attribute with a decompiler like ildasm.exe