# Check the .Net Application version

Tags: .net

I have a vb.net Console Application with source code. I need to know which version of .Net had been used to build the the application. Is there any method to check the version?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine .NET Framework version for dll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3460982/determine-net-framework-version-for-dll)

Comment: not sure, if he means this.  Do you have a sourcecodeproject or a compiled dll ?

Comment: I have a source code.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) to determine referenced dll-s.