Use Ookii.Dialogs.WinForms.dll (InputDialog) in Powershell?
I am looking to leverage the Ookii.Dialogs.WinForms dll (For .Net Framework) that will allow me to expand on the basic message boxes that PowerShell offers out of the box. I have successfully gotten the TaskDialog working, but currently running into an issue trying to get the InputDialog to work. I seem to have all the syntax correct, but upon running, I receive the error below.
Error:
Exception calling "ShowDialog" with "0" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Resources.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot 
find the file specified."

Of course, the error gives me some idea what is happening and I have even gone as far as downloading and importing the referenced missing assembly and still no luck.
Add-Type -Path "C:\System.Resources.Extensions.dll"

Ookii.Dialogs.WinForms

Github: https://github.com/ookii-dialogs/ookii-dialogs-winforms

Nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ookii.Dialogs.WinForms


System.Resources.Extensions

System.Resources.Extensions: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Resources.Extensions

My System Details:

Windows 11 Home (Version: 23H2)
.Net Framework: 4.8.09032
PowerShell: 5.1

All .Net Versions Installed:

My Code:
# Loading all possible assemblies (Yes, I know this is overkill - but trying to find what works)
Add-Type -AssemblyName System, System.Windows.Forms, System.Drawing, PresentationCore, Presentationframework, Microsoft.VisualBasic, WindowsFormsIntegration
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

# Load Ookii.Dialogs.WinForms dll into session (.dll from Nuget Package - net462)
Add-Type -Path "C:\Ookii.Dialogs.WinForms.dll"

# Build/Show cleaner InputDialog (Not the ugly Visual Basic one)
$InputDialog = [Ookii.Dialogs.WinForms.InputDialog]::new()
$InputDialog.WindowTitle = 'Input Dialog'
$InputDialog.MainInstruction = 'This is the main instruction area.'
$InputDialog.Content = 'This is me testing the content area. Just adding more info.'
$InputDialog.Input ='Placeholder'
$InputDialog.ShowDialog()


Does form run in c#?  I think issue is with version of Net installed on machine.  I think version 4  : Version=4.0.0.0 is Net 4.0.  You are referencing Net 4.6.2.

@jdweng I have no idea if it runs in C#. I am strictly running through PowerShell only. My current .net version is 4.8 so I should have no issues as the minimum requirement is 4.6.2. Are you saying I somehow need to target 4.0 specifically? If so, how would I go about doing that via loading it as an assembly?

You would need at least Net 4.0 install on machine.  You can open dll with notepad and check net version.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3460982/determine-net-framework-version-for-dll

Am I missing something here? The error above spits out v4.0.0.0. I am currently using the 4.6.2 .NET framework variant of the .dll. As stated in my original post, I am currently on .NET 4.8 as the latest version on my machine. @jdweng I meet the requirements to successfully run/show the InputDialog... but clearly missing something else at this point.

Prior to Net 4.3 you need to install all previous version of Net.  Each Net release was only changes from previous releases.  4.3 or later all Net libraries were in a single release.  Visual Studio allows you to target any installed version of Net.  If you are using 4.6.2 library you need any libraries referenced by the dll installed on the machine.

In Windows 10/11, you cannot install prior to .net 4.6/4.8 as these are the base versions in the OS itself. I even tried a quick .net 4.0 & 4.6.2 offline installer and would not let me install due to my latest version. I have updated my original post with an image reflecting all the current versions running on my machine to hopefully give some clues. I feel like we are back at the beginning and is this more of an issue targeting the right .net in my PowerShell session?

Powershell 5.1 is built using Net 4.5.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/whats-new/differences-from-windows-powershell?view=powershell-7.4  I'm not sure if going to a later version of PS will allow a Net 4.6.2 dll to run.  Powershell 6.0 is built on Net 2.0 (not Framework).

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Okay, so after plenty of digging and information provided by @jdweng in terms of the correct .NET version and what "can" be ran officially.. I ended up grabbing the latest version of Ookii.Dialogs that was built on on .NET 4.5 and of course, it just worked.
Hopefully this will help benefit anyone searching and wanting to use this .dll strictly through PowerShell 5.1.


Nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ookii.Dialogs.WinForms/1.2.0

Here is my working InputDialog :)

