# build managed c++ project in .net 3.5 using vs2010 (msbuild4)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, .net-3.5, managed, msbuild-4.0

Is it possible to build a managed c++ project in .net 3.5 using vs2010 ?
There are different opinions around but I haven't being able to do this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build system for VS2010 was dramatically changed and only directly supports building for 4.0.  Targeting 3.5 requires having VS2008 on your machine.  More about this in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921702/change-c-cli-project-to-another-framework-than-4-0-with-vs2010/2921868#2921868).

Comment: thanks! We are currently confronted with exactly this situation: asking our developers to have both versions of studio installed.