# Recompiling code by earlier version of the framework?

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli

| wrote C++/CLI code with .NET framework 4.0.30319, I would like to recompile it again with the earlier version of the framework. How can I proceed in that in MS VS?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change C++/CLI project to another framework than 4.0 with vs2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921702/change-c-cli-project-to-another-framework-than-4-0-with-vs2010)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the project properties Application tab you can set the version of the .NET framework that's targetted by the assembly.
But if you're using any features that are specific to .NET 4 then you'll need to rework your code to do it in a way that's compatible with the older version.

Comment: You need an earlier version of Visual C++ to do this.  Visual Studio supports multi-targeting, but the C++/CLI compiler itself doesn't.