# Which VC++ Runtime do I need if I'm using C++/CLI in VS 2010?

Tags: .net, visual-c++, deployment, installation, runtime

Which VC++ Runtime do I need to package with my app installer if I'm using C++/CLI in VS 2010? Assuming the target PC is running Windows XP/Vista/7 and has no other VC++ Runtime installed.

1. Visual C++ 2005 -- 3 MB
2. Visual C++ 2005 SP1 -- 3 MB
3. Visual C++ 2008 -- 2 MB
4. Visual C++ 2008 SP1 -- 4 MB

I'm [targeting .NET 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2921868/1294758) although I'm building the app with `ToolsVersion` set to `"4.0"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your job ll be done by using this one.

Visual C++ 2008 -- 2 MB

I am using the same.

Comment: Why not SP1? Can you give more information? Are you also using C++/CLI in VS 2010 and targeting the .NET 2.0 framework?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I am seeing C++/CLI, which means that you might need to redistribute the .Net framework also. Most probably framework 2.0 but not sure. You should also check it.

Alternatively, if you are not using CLI, you should remove it from project preference and as suggested by AB Bolim you can go with redistributing C++ 2008

Comment: Would VC++ 2010 be better?

Comment: You must distribute that runtime against which you have built your application. So, if you have built it against VC2008 runtime, you must redistribute it to make it run.

Comment: I don't know which runtime I'm building against, all I know is that I'm targeting .NET 2.0 - is that VC2008?

Comment: If you want to develop for .Net, C# should be the language of choice. With VC++ you will not get autocomplete and intellisense support from visual studio and it is rumored that microsoft will in future discontinue supporting this architecture. Only reason you should choose C++ for .Net is if you already have considerably developed code in c++ and you do not want to rewrite it.

Answer (score 1):

Use Dependency Walker (http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to inspect your mixed mode assembly, it will show you the runtime your assembly depends upon.