# C++ setting the .NET Framework version

Tags: .net, frameworks, c++-cli, version

This should be really easy, I've searched online for hours and throughout my project files as well for an answer to no avail.

Majority of the 'answers' I've found online say to get to the project's properties one way or another. Then click the Application tab on the left hand column in the properties window.
I've done that and I do not have an Application tab, in fact I'm finding the properties window I see is extremely different than what is shown in the examples.

Mainly it's a difference between a C++ project and other projects apparently, which leads me to the 2nd link at the end of this post.

I'm instructed to do the following (and yes I've found this file just fine)

> In the project file, locate the entry for the target Framework version.
>   For example, if your project is designed to use the .NET Framework 4.5, 
>   locate v4.5 in the 
>    element of the  element. If the
>    element isn't present, your project doesn't use
>   the .NET Framework and no change is required.
>   That element is not present for me, and it says no change is required. But when I try to use something that is new to v4.5 of the framework I am unable to. (such as Windows.UI)

These MSDN pages are where I keep ending up on my various internet searches for a solution, and neither has helped.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb398202

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff770576.aspx

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't this be tagged as `c++-cli` instead of `c++`?

Comment: First link you post is for a C# project so doesn't apply for you, as I assume you are using C++/CLI projects? Anyway, seocnd link seems correct; at least that is how we do it: put `<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>` in a `PropertyGroup`

Comment: Here are more details (seems to be a duplicate): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921702/change-c-cli-project-to-another-framework-than-4-0-with-vs2010

Comment: Sorry if my post is a duplicate, I did search but not for a C++-cli tag (honestly didn't know the difference to begin to look for that)

I've tried the solution but am seeing no difference. Perhaps I am doing something else wrong when trying to use the Windows::UI features
My apologies if my inexperience/understanding is the problem.

Added this to the project file with seemingly no change
<PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
</PropertyGroup>

Comment: You did add it somewhere at the top, right? Anyway it's probably better to post some simple code to reproduce the problem else we cannot really see what is going on

Comment: It's before any item groups and after the Project Toolsversion


What I'm trying to use is the Windows::UI features, like CoreWindow. Everything I found online shows that it was introduced in the .Net framework as of version 4.5 which is what lead me here since no matter what files I tried to include it wouldn't even let me use the Windows::UI namespace let alone any features within it.


In other words, I have no code to show since I can't even begin.