# C++ class dll how can be used in .net3.5 c#

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll, clr

I have find many ways to make c# can use c++ dll.I used clr c++ to wrap the native c++ dll . 
But I need to use in c# with .net 3.5,it has the trouble

> because it does the .NET Framework assembly "mscorlib, Version =
>   4.0.0.0, Culture = Neutral, PublicKeyToken = b77a5c561934e089 "has an indirect dependency, and the version of the assembly is" 4.0.0.0 ",
>   higher than the version" 2.0.0.0 "in the current target framework

.
The c++ dll is bulit in .net2.0 and clr dll also in .net2.0.
How to  resolve the problem? Thank you!

Comment: One of the assemblies you are referencing is in .NET 4.0 OR one of your projects is in .NET 4.0... Find which one is. If you open your dll/exe with ILSpy you should be able to see each one which .NET is targetting.

Comment: @xanatos By the ILSpy,  th clr c++ dll has `mscorlib` , is  Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 . Others are Version=2.0.0.0.

Comment: There is a bug... It could be you are affected: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/780602/compiling-c-clr-dll-in-vs-2012-targeting-net-2-0-introduces-indirect-dependency-on-net-4-0#tabs What Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: Probably a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2921868/613130 (where Hans repeats that you need older versions of Visual Studio installed to do it)

Comment: @vs2015with update 3. I also bulit in .net3.5.  The problem are still existing.

Comment: I'll say that they left the bug "as is" after VS 2012 :-(

Comment: Thank you very much! I know what need to do. Because I work with unity in .net 3.5. I will  install vs2010

Comment: Then I'll close this as a duplicate

Comment: I had a try. I find I need vs2008. And .NET Framework Versions and Dependencies: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb822049.aspx

Comment: Yes :-) When you said "I will install vs2010" I had a suspect it was the wrong version... (because Hans Passant wrote explicitly: *For example, if you specify v3.5, which represents the .NET Framework v3.5, Visual Studio 2008 SP1 must be installed.*)